# Running GUI Application from docker, QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'

Tags: docker

I am fairly new to Docker (learned about it yesterday, found it interesting) and have absolutely no skill with it so please try to make your answer as noob friendly as possible.
I ran a ubuntu image and tried to install and run wireshark in it (GUI based packet catcher) but on running I got the following error :

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
dbus[2537]: The last reference on a connection was dropped without closing the connection. This is a bug in an application. See dbus_connection_unref() documentation for details.
Most likely, the application was supposed to call dbus_connection_close(), since this is a private connection.
  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I made my docker container with :

`sudo docker run --name ubuntu -v /home/anmol/Projects/Docker/Ubuntu/:/home -it --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" --env="DISPLAY" --net=host ubuntu`

Additionally, I have tried :

`xhost +local:docker`

which didn't work so I tried :

`xhost +`

which also didn't work and I kept getting the same error.

I have a feeling I am supposed to install some x11 package inside my container but I don't know which one or if that is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

After writing `xhost +x` if you add `--privileged` in your docker command, it should work.

```
sudo docker run -it \
   --privileged \
   -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
   -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority \
    <imageId>
```

However, it is not secure to use `xhost +x` and `--privileged`. They are not recommended to be used in a production environment, because they **expose**  the kernel and the hardware resources of the host.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the issue and followed @Doğuş and @Casey Jones as references, which almost helped.
Still faced the issue of not setting the host to that machine.

So my updated command is as follows

> docker run -it --privileged --net=host-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v
> $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority <IMAGE_ID> /bin/bash

where IMAGE_ID  is your docker image id.